# Decrypt RSA public key in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, openssl, sscrypto

I have troubles with decrypting RSA public keys in Cocoa environment.
I have encrypted hash, public key in public.pem with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` guards (generated by openssl)

```
NSData *encryptedData = base64dec(license);

NSString *publicKeyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"public" ofType:@"pem"];
NSData *publicKeyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:publicKeyPath];

SSCrypto *crypto = [[SSCrypto alloc] initWithPublicKey:publicKeyData];

[crypto setClearTextWithData:encryptedData];
[crypto verify];

NSString *verifiedKey = [crypto clearTextAsString];
```

But `verifiedKey` is always nil. Looks like SSCrypto can't convert NSData to NSString. How can I actually get data decrypted?

---

Ended up using this code (to eliminate base64 decoding step)

```
[crypto setCipherTextFromBase64String:license];
NSString *verifiedKey = [crypto clearTextAsString];
```

But `verifiedKey` is always an empty string. What does it mean? Input data seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are decrypting encrypted data, you should do setCipherText: instead of setClearTextWithData:

Also, calling verify without using its return value serves no purpose.

Comment: please take a look at my update. Now I'm getting empty string, what does it mean?

Comment: @dig Where are you getting your base64 encoding/decoding functions? I suggest you use the base64 functionality provided in SSCrypto instead, since differences in where newlines are placed (etc.) could render SSCrypto unable to decode the data encoded with another library.